# Trying to search a column on SQLite Python so that it only returns the information searched

Tags: python, database, sqlite

New to Python and Databases

I have a database table set up with a column of usernames. I want the user to be able to search through the table via a raw_input and only return the values which are associated with that user name.

E.g. user searches for Bill and it only displays Bill's records ordered by a specified column

This is what I have so far but its obviously VERY wrong, hope someone can help:

```
def find_me(db, column_name):
    db = sqlite3.connect(db)
    cursor = db.cursor()
    name = raw_input("Please enter your username: ")
    cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM username WHERE name=?", (name,))
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM username ORDER BY "+column_name+" ASC")
    name = cursor.fetchone()
    next = cursor.fetchone()
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is wrong here and what do you want?

Comment: When the user searches it seems to show all of the users rather than just isolating the name that they searched (raw_input) and displaying only their details from the table. I want it so that a user can search for only their information based on name input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to make the query similar to the following:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM username WHERE name=?", (name,))
```

This uses query parameters, so it's correctly escaped for the data provided. Then just adapt this to SELECT * and whatever else you want from the result.

---

Try working with this:

```
name = raw_input("Please enter your username: ")
query = "SELECT * FROM username WHERE name=? ORDER BY {0}".format(column_name)
cursor.execute(query, (name,))
for row in cursor:
    print row
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, I have added in the part you said but it still does not work. I edited the code above so can you check its input correctly? Only been doing databases a couple of days so only just getting to grips with it. Thanks again

Comment: @user1847644 updated slightly to show a simple example of looping over the results...

Comment: That seems to work but its only displaying one of the users inputs. Any idea why that could be?

Comment: Ignore that last comment. That works!!. Thank you very much, thats been bugging me for too long!